# How do I modify the search query on a subscription?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I've implemented an instant search by adapting the example given [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/temporary-ui-state) where I can filter the tasks by referencing a state variable I set.

How do I do this though by modifying a query in the subscription?

Currently the subscription is done as follows:

```
export default createContainer( () => {
    // Meteor.subscribe( 'Tasks' , '' );
    Meteor.subscribe( 'Tasks' );
    return {
        tasks : Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
    };  
} , App );
```

and on the server

```
Meteor.publish( 'Tasks' , function tasksPublication() {
    return Tasks.find( {} , { sort : { createdAt : -1 } } );
});
```

I would like to make it as so:

```
export default createContainer( () => {
    // if I hardcode searchStr it it works eg 'Task Name'
    Meteor.subscribe( 'Tasks' , searchStr ); 
    return {
        tasks : Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
    };  
} , App );
```

and on the server

```
Meteor.publish( 'Tasks' , function tasksPublication(query) {
    check(query, String);
    return Tasks.find({
        name : { $regex : query , $options : 'i' }
    }, {
        sort : { createdAt : -1 }
    });
});
```

I don't know how to get the value that I've hard coded programmatically from the state of App. Even though in App I can access it using `this.state.searchString`.

Any help welcome
thank you

**EDIT 1**

in *imports/ui/App.jsx*

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
             searchStr : '' ,
        };
    }

export default createContainer( (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    Meteor.subscribe( 'Tasks' );
    return {
        tasks : Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
    };
}, App );
```

in *client/main.jsx*

```
import App from '../imports/ui/App.jsx';

Meteor.startup( () => {
    render( <App searchStr={this.state.searchStr} />, document.getElementById('render-target' ) );
});
```

I get the following error message:

> Cannot read property 'searchStr' of undefined

Which to be honest I think makes sense because I'm guessing the constructor of App hasn't run yet. But the question remains, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass props to `createContainer` through callback parameters.

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
    Meteor.subscribe('Tasks', props.searchStr); 
    return {
        tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
    };  
}, SearchResults);
```

And then just pass the `searchStr` to your component as a property.

```
import SearchResults from ...

export class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchString: ''
    };
  }

  // ...insert app logic that updates state.searchString.

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="search query" ... />
      <SearchResults searchStr={this.state.searchString} />
    </div>;
  }
}
```

---

*Bonus protip:*

You can also set the `propTypes` of the container created by `createContainer`:

```
export default const MyComponent = createContainer((props) => {
  ...
}, SearchResults);

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  searchStr: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: is the `<My Component searchStr="boo" /> simply to initialise it? and then I can modify it in the component code?

Comment: No, it works as an immutable prop. Use it like `<MyComponent searchStr={this.state.searchStr} />`

Comment: Hm.. `<MyComponent searchStr={this.state.searchStr} />` gave me `'searchQuery' undefined` should I initialise this somehow?

Comment: What is seachQuery? If your App uses this.state.searchString, then use it like <MyComponent searchStr={this.state.searchString} />

Comment: sorry that's what I meant, I'll update the answer to show what the current structure looks like

Comment: Ok, that doesn't really make sense. You need to use `<MyComponent searchStr={this.state.searchString} />` inside `App`'s `render` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110017/discussion-between-evan54-and-aedm).

Comment: ok I edited the answer, please can you accept it and I will then accept the answer. Thank you